# Passing data between UIPageViewController Child views with Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

I cant seem to find a specific answer to my direct dilemma.

I have a `UIPageViewController` that programmatically loads through 6 child `UIView` scenes. They host various stages of an 'add' element functionality. Currently the `PageViewController` Class adds each child view into an array and instantiates them when required with:

```
storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editViewController")
```

The natural delegate is set-up to swipe between each child scene and therefore no "`prepareForSegue`" function is run.

As the pages swipe, a new scene with different identifier is instantiated.

From my reading, I am now attempting to set-up a delegate that takes an instance of a Dictionary, that reads/stores input from each stage (different child `UIPageView` scenes) of the process and updates the Dictionary.

I am using the "`viewWillDissapear`" and "`viewWillAppear`" methods to help set-up the passing data into the delegate.

Unfortunately I am running into problems, and due to my lack of experience, and not much on this specific problem, I'm needing help!

Main question:

Can I set-up a data delegate in the `UIPageViewController` class, that 'talks' or can be accessed by the child `UIViews`?

OR

Does anyone know of a good solution to pass my Dictionary from child to child to child????

Comment: I have a similar question - I'd like to know how to pass data from the PageViewController down to the children

Comment: Luke, I found a solution for a similar issue I'm having that may work for you - will post as an answer.

Comment: I really give up to try do it using protocols or notificationcenter, Im just using a UserDefaults, and work well

Answer (score 7):

Instead of passing data from child->child, you could pass it from child->parent->child.

First, when you instantiate each child in the PageViewController with **storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editViewController")**, save a reference to it.

So something like

```
var firstViewController: EditViewController?
...
firstViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editViewController") as EditViewController
```

Next, get a reference in each child ViewController to the PageViewController using **self.parentViewController**.

```
var myPageViewController: PageViewContrller (or whatever yours is called) 
....
myPageViewController = self.parentViewController() as PageViewController (or whatever yours is called)
```

Now, using those two references, you can call functions in the PageViewController and in the children to pass data back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

You should look over the UIPageViewController delegate [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/).

You get these 2 methods that gets called before and after the transition between the viewcontrollers.

```
- pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers: // called before the transition starts
- pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:  // called after the transition is finished
```

Comment: These methods are really helpful. we can get the previous and next viewController and we can just call their methods and pass data through those methods after typecasting

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy to send data from PageViewController to its childs without using any segues

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      self.delegate=self
      self.dataSource=self
    let childViewController=storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "some identifier of view") as! ChildViewController
    if let cid = challengeId{
        print("Page Challenge id \(cid)")
    childViewController.challengeId=cid
    }
```